# Getting hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

getting hashmaps problem.

I tried getting the `hashmap` outside the `if (BookValues.containsKey(ID))` and i would always getting:

> java nullpointer exception

here's the code : 
(let's assume this has been declared. I used Integer,Class for my hashmap)

```
    int targetID = BookValues.get(ID).BookID.intValue();
    String targetTitle = BookValues.get(ID).Title.toString();
    String targetAuthor= BookValues.get(ID).Author.toString();
    int targetCopies=BookValues.get(ID).Copies.intValue();
```

whenever i code it inside the contains key, it works but when i do it outside it runs into an error. I was thinking of getting it outside the `.containsKey`because it would make my code longer and i'm trying to save spaCan somebody explain it to me?

Comment: The `HashMap` returns null if the key does not exist.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-

Comment: What would you expect it to do when `BookValues.get(ID).Title.intValue()` is called and `ID` is not an existing key in the map?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please add the stack trace of the error.

Comment: why don't you apply **null check** after getting key from hashmap before performing further opertions.

Comment: Agree with "dazito", "ernest_k" and "kamlesh pandey". Also, null reference check is a part of good programming practice.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
int targetID = BookValues.get(ID).BookID.intValue();
String targetTitle = BookValues.get(ID).Title.toString();
String targetAuthor= BookValues.get(ID).Author.toString();
int targetCopies=BookValues.get(ID).Copies.intValue();
```

has quite a few places where exceptions could be thrown.

`BookValues.get(ID)` will give you the object if it exists or `null` if it doesn't. To avoid a possible `NullPointerException` this line should be broken up. The following assumes your map's values are `BookValue` objects.

```
BookValue value = BookValues.get(ID);
if (value != null) {
    int targetId = value.BookID.intValue();
    String targetTitle = value.Title.toString();
    String targetAuthor = value.Author.toString();
    int copies = value.Copies.intValue();
    // rest of code here
} else {
    // TODO do something if there's no value in the map for the specified key
}
```

Note that in this way, you also avoid repeating the `.get(ID)` on .

Consider also following the [java code conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html)